# Programmatically Share Editing Rights of Google Site using a Google Form (Semi-Public Wiki)

Tags: google-apps-script, wiki

I have an existing (classic) Google Site that I would like to be a semi-public wiki. Google seems to have explicitly disallowed public wikis in the new version of sites, so I'm trying to find a work-around of sorts.

Here's my ideal flow:

```
1. Guest visits my Google site "Foo Wiki" and clicks a link to become a contributor.

2. Link goes to my Google Form "Registration Form" that just asks for
   a name and email address.

3. Form submission creates a new line in a google sheet "Registration List".

4. "Registration List" has a script that emails the user's given email address 
    giving them editing rights to "Foo Wiki"
```

Is this possible?

I have the easy parts (1-3) done, but not sure how to go about step 4.

Comment: Yes that possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can easily get this done using the `addEditor()` api.

Kindly check this out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#addEditor(User)

Comment: Thanks! I actually realized I used the "classic" sites system, so this will work I think!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was even easier than I thought! I sent a second edit invite by email to another email address I had and copied the invite acceptance link to be on my site.